# magento mobileshoppe theme - Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in

Tags: magento

I am using mobileshoppe magento theme for our store, when i installed magento it was showing latest products on home page using the code below.

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Then we customized the theme and it stopped to display latest products on home page even the code above is as it is in admin.

It shows the error - 
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSize() on a non-object in D:\wamp\www\magento\app\design\frontend\default\mobileshoppe\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar_top.phtml on line 34

toolbar_top.phtml

```
 <?php if($this->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>
 <div class="toolbar">
<?php if( $this->isExpanded() ): ?>
<div class="sorter">
    <?php if( $this->isEnabledViewSwitcher() ): ?>
    <p class="view-mode">
        <?php $_modes = $this->getModes(); ?>
        <?php if($_modes && count($_modes)>1): ?>
        <label><?php echo $this->__('View as') ?>:</label>
        <?php foreach ($this->getModes() as $_code=>$_label): ?>
            <?php if($this->isModeActive($_code)): ?>
                <strong title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></strong>&nbsp;
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->getModeUrl($_code) ?>" title="<?php echo $_label ?>" class="<?php echo strtolower($_code); ?>"><?php echo $_label ?></a>&nbsp;
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </p>
    <?php endif; ?>


     <div class="limiter">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Show') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach ($this->getAvailableLimit() as  $_key=>$_limit): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getLimitUrl($_key) ?>"<?php if($this->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                <?php echo $_limit ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select> <?php echo $this->__('per page') ?>
    </div>

    <div class="sort-by">
        <label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
        <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
        <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
        <?php if($this->getCurrentDirection() == 'desc'): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'asc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_desc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Ascending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl(null, 'desc') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/i_asc_arrow.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Set Descending Direction') ?>" class="v-middle" /></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

can anyone please help me on this? Thanks...

Comment: Please post the contents of that file.

Comment: does it work with the original theme? what modifications have you made?

Comment: chjohasbrouck, updated the question with code file.

Comment: OSdave, basically have done css and html changes and installed new extensions like wordpress blog.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Guys I had the same issue on my Mobileshoppe Template. I tried to add products of a category and it didn't work for me.

In the end the solution was to use as mentioned on the official Mobileshoppe page "readme" file: http://magresponsive.devdemoz.com/readme.html

I used the code where it says: 2) Create cms page (home page) step bellow.

Hope it helps somebody.